# Can I issue media queries in millimeters?

Tags: html, css, typography

I've got some text that I'd like to adjust for legibility on very small screens. However, I can't seem to get the media queries to work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 60mm) {
    body {
        font-size: 14px;                                                                              
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. Use px instead.

Comment: Answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The CSS3 [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) recommendation contains an example with `min-width: 25cm`, and there is no reason why you could not use `mm` as well, especially since the recommendation normatively cites [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) for definitions of values. Any CSS 2.1 length unit is allowed in the value of `max-width`. This also works in those browsers that support CSS3 media queries in the first place (tested on IE, Chrome, Firefox).

So if it does not work, the problem is elsewhere. Since it may be difficult to make the viewport as narrow as 60mm, test first with 160mm. (It seems that IE 10 does not let you make the viewport 60mm wide, but this has nothing to do with the browser support to the `mm` unit in this context.) Also check that the property you are using within the `@media` rule is not overridden by other rules. Try testing first with some property that you do not set at all in your stylesheets.

Note that `mm` does not necessarily correspond to the physical unit (well, multiple of a unit) millimeter. As described in the CSS Values and Units Module Level 3 CR, the so-called [absolute lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) like `mm` aren’t really absolute but may depend on device resolution and expected viewing distance. Moreover, small devices often scale the content by default.

Comment: Well, hush my mouth, it looks like you're right. However, I just had a go with Chrome and I can't get it to work at all - it always triggers, no matter the size of the window or the number of mm I use.

Comment: @Grim, it works fine when I test on Chrome (29beta) on Win 7. Check your CSS code with a validator, and post a sample document if problems remain.

Comment: This is not working for me in Chrome mobile (ver 67.0.3396.87).It works on firefox desktop, firefox focus mobile, edge, but won't work in chrome mobile. Unlike @Grim, for me the max-width does not activate, even though my max-width trigger is set at 210mm (which, of course, my mobile does not have). Actually, i am not changing the font-size, but the content in a "before" selector.